# Typescript - Generic for deriving the same type but with no properties undefined

Tags: typescript

I have a type with some possibly undefined fields

```
type Foo = { 
  a: string | undefined
  b: string
  c: string | undefined
}
```

I want the same type, but declaring that **none** of the fields are undefined

```
type Bar = { 
  a: string
  b: string
  c: string
}
```

I'd like a way to derive `Bar` from `Foo`, so that I don't have to manually create `Bar` and update it when Foo changes. Something like this

```
type Bar = NoPropertiesUndefined<Foo>
```

**Is there any generic like this built into Typescript?**

A note on usecase - I'm using this when I get the type `Foo` as an input, then validate it to check no fields are undefined, then pass to another function for further processing. I'd like that other function to take a `Bar` argument, and have the validator return a `Bar` or throw, to ensure I've validated the `Foo` in a typesafe way. The `Foo` types can even be dynamically created themselves using `ReturnType` - so even the cumbersome nature of manually defining `Bar` aside, in some cases it's not even possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `NoPropertiesUndefined` generic from the question can be implemented like this

```
type NoPropertiesUndefined<T> = { [P in keyof T]: NonNullable<T[P]> }
```

You use it like:

```
type Bar = NoPropertiesUndefined<Foo>
```

`Bar` then has all the same fields as `Foo`, just none of them can be undefined.

---

<sub>I'll accept my own answer as it directly solves the exact problem I had, but I came to this solution via the answer from Yoni Gibbs, which mentions the related `Required` built in generic from which I got the inspiration for the above implementation. Please upvote that answer if you find this one useful!</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Do you need to declare your type as above, or could you slightly change it to this instead:

```
type Foo = { 
  a?: string
  b: string
  c?: string
}
```

If you can do that then the built-in `Required` generic will do what you want, I think:

```
type NoUndefinedFoo = Required<Foo>
```

See [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#example-6) for details.

Here's how that generic type is defined:

```
type Required<T> = { [P in keyof T]-?: T[P] };
```

i.e. it removes the `?` from every property of the `T` you pass into `Required`.

Comment: This has been extremely helpful, thanks. I do need to have the possibly undefined properties on `Foo` for reasons I won't go into, but the implementation of `Required<T>` here has led me to the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```js
type Foo = { 
  a: string
  b: string
  c: string
}
```

None of those properties can be undefined - if you've enabled strict null checks in your TSConfig.

In strict `null` checking mode, the `null` and `undefined` values are not in the domain of every type and are only assignable to themselves and `any` (the one exception being that `undefined` is also assignable to `void`).

Also, I think you're looking for this...

```js
type NonNullable<T> = T extends null ? never : T
// Exclude null and undefined from T
```

Usage:

```js
type Bar = NonNullable<Foo>;
```

Comment: But `Foo` *does* have possibly undefined fields - this isn't something I can just change, that's kind of the problem.

Comment: Also the `NonNullable` generic is not what I need, that just works on the top level - i.e. in that example any variable with type `Bar` would not be undefined, but its properties still could be